# How to keep network connections up while sleeping VirtualBox (Genymotion)

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, sleep, android-studio

I am using Virtual Box very often and at least one box is up when my mac is working. In my case I use emulator `Genymotion` that is based on `VirtualBox engine`, it uses local network connection for communication between user and UI of the Android VM. So network is essential in this case. Furthermore, I am using VPN sometimes, VPN connection is lost as well.

When my laptop goes into sleep mode it closes all connections as I can guess, so when it is up again. I have something like - `192.168.56.101 - OFFLINE` in Android Studio (adb).

So I have to restart my VMs if mac goes into sleep mode.

Is there any way to keep some connections up. at least from local network/localhost ?

This problem was on El Captain and still on macOS Sierra as well.

I would be grateful for any help or advice how to solve this issue.

Thx.